# Mounting Drives, Replacing with an Array

Tags: mount, raid, plex

So I currently have a boot drive, and a 500gb Drive, and a 2TB Drive. I have just aquired a HP ProLiant Microserver, and I will be aquiring 4x2TB Drives in around a month, which I will put in Raid 5.

I was hoping to set up Plex to serve as a media center, however I believe it will dislike it if I suddenly create new directories later on for it. So I wanted to know if the following would work.

I have mnt/md0/ then I run;

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mnt/md0
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb3 /mnt/md0
```

And I would end up with the following mounted to that folder;

From sdb2:

```
mnt/md0/Anime
mnt/md0/Movies
mnt/md0/Music
mnt/md0/Podcasts
```

And from sdb3:

```
mnt/md0/TV
```

So that later when I replace the two drives with the Raid 5 Array (md0) and mount it to mnt/ all the dir's would be the same?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of virtual filesystem that can merge two real locations into one. You have to mount each separately but you can then combine those mountpoints into one.

One problem is determining where new files are written so for simplicity, the one I use is readonly (and I write to the direct mounts). This will work for you.

This is what I'd have in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /media/sdb2
ntfs-3g /dev/sdb3 /media/sdb3
none    /mnt/md0  aufs  ro,br=/media/sdb2:/media/sdb3 0 0
```

And you'd replace all three lines with your array later on.